# Keras Fit_generator not reporting progress or in Validation Step or Verbose not enabled for validation

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

Below is the code for a CNN mode.  I am able to see the EPOCH progress bar for Training, but not for the validation. It seems like the execution was STUCK at Validation , but not.. at last it printed the validation results. 
What could I modify in the below code for enabling Verbose during Validation

```
batch_size=64
h5_path = "EPOC_1_Feb_25_model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(h5_path, monitor='val_acc',save_weights_only=True, verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

history = model.fit_generator(
    data_gen(train, id_label_map, batch_size, augment=True),
    validation_data=data_gen(train2, id_label_map, batch_size),
    epochs=1, verbose=1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint],
    steps_per_epoch=len(train) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(train2) // batch_size)
model.load_weights(h5_path)
```

> Epoch 1/1
>   11/11 [==============================] - 262s 24s/step - loss: 0.4654 - acc: 0.8345 - weighted_loss: 0.4848 - val_loss: 0.4907 - val_acc: 0.8014 - val_weighted_loss: 0.4936
>
> Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.80137, saving model to EPOC_1_Feb_25_model.h5

I wish to see the progress like

> Epoch 1/1
>   5/11  *Validation* [==================.......]  * # Kind of Progress for Validation ALSO*

Instead a Sudden Jump to val_loss: 0.4907 - val_acc: 0.8014 - val_weighted_loss: 0.4936

Answer (score 1):

This issue solution is In Progress, see [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28648][1]

Mean while, the below workaround would help . User Custom Call Backs

```
import datetime
class ReportValidationStatus(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

        def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
            print('Evaluating: batch {} begins at {}'.format(batch, datetime.now().time()))

        def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
            print('Evaluating: batch {} ends at {}'.format(batch, datetime.now().time()))
```

---

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    data_gen(train, id_label_map,id_pz_map,train_images_dir, batch_size, augment=True),
    validation_data=data_gen(train, id_label_map,id_pz_map,train_images_dir, batch_size, augment=False),
    epochs=3, verbose=1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint,ReportValidationStatus()],
    steps_per_epoch=len(train) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(val) // batch_size)

enter code here
```

> This may print some wired progress statement, but you would not be
>   left clueless about the progress. Secondly you may notice for the
>   first Epoch it may print the validation in progress.